# A combinatorial identity $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni \binom{-n}{k-i} =0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can anyone prove the following identity for me?
$\sum_{i=0}^k
\begin{pmatrix}
n\\
i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-n\\
k-i
\end{pmatrix}=0$ for any positive integers $n,k$.
I'm pretty sure this is correct. But I cannot convince myself with a specific proof, even though I've done a serious calculation.
It may be just a simple verification.

Comment: This is just the coefficient of $T^k$ in $(1+T)^n(1+T^{-n})=1$ .

Comment: @abx Did you mean to write $(1+T)^{-n}$ instead of $(1+T^{-n})$?

Comment: Perhaps this could be migrated to math.SE before it gains too many downvotes?

Comment: Yes! and yes @AndrewMuzie, sorry for the typo.

Comment: See Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.

Comment: You might have a look at [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity). The Wikipedia article says: *The identity generalizes to non-integer arguments. In this case, it is known as the Chu–Vandermonde identity.*

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion given in [the first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697440/a-combinatorial-identity-sum-i-0k-binom-ni-binom-nk-i-0#comment1460946_697440) we will use the fact that $(1+x)^n(1+x)^{-n}=1$ together with [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}k.$$

We get
$$1=(1+x)^n(1+x)^{-n} = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni x^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{-n}j x^j = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni \binom{-n}{k-i} x^k.$$
Comparing the coefficients on both sides we see that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni \binom{-n}{k-i} =
\begin{cases} 1,& k=0 \\ 0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

---

This is a special case of [Chu=Vandermonde identity](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity).
$$\sum_i \binom ri \binom s{k-i} = \binom{r+s}k$$
which is obtained for $r=n$ and $s=-n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\left.\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{n \choose j}{-n \choose k - j}
\right\vert_{\ k,\,n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{+}}} & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{n \choose j}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{-n} \over z^{k - j + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{{-n \choose k - j}}}
\\[3mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{-n} \over z^{k + 1}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{n \choose j}z^{j}}^{\ds{\pars{1 + z}^{k}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k - n} \over z^{k + 1}}\
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & = \color{#f00}{{k - n \choose k}}\tag{1}
\\[3mm] & = \color{#f00}{{n - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

In any case $\pars{~\pars{1}\ \mbox{or}\ \pars{2}~}$,
$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{\sum_{j = 0}^{k}{n \choose j}{-n \choose k - j}}} =
\ds{\color{#f00}{0}\,,\quad\forall\ k,n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{+}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$